# Get user data from Spotify on Android

Tags: java, android, curl, spotify

I want to get the current user's data from spotify.

The documentation says I have to use this command:

> curl -X GET "https://api.spotify.com/v1/me" -H "Authorization: Bearer
>   {your access token}"

I successfully get the token string from Spotify.
**My question is:**  How should I transform this CURL command to java?

Comment: I think you simply need to make an HTTP GET or POST request and in response it will return JSON data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need language bindings and an HTTP client. A lot of this work has been done already in the [Android client made by Kaaes](https://github.com/kaaes/spotify-web-api-android).

In your very specific case, you'd use the `getMe` method as documented [here](http://kaaes.github.io/spotify-web-api-android/javadoc/kaaes/spotify/webapi/android/SpotifyService.html#getMe()). This returns a [UserPrivate](http://kaaes.github.io/spotify-web-api-android/javadoc/kaaes/spotify/webapi/android/models/UserPrivate.html) object, which contains birthdate, product, email, country, as well as the fields available in the [UserPublic](http://kaaes.github.io/spotify-web-api-android/javadoc/kaaes/spotify/webapi/android/models/UserPublic.html) object, like display_name.

[Full documentation](http://kaaes.github.io/spotify-web-api-android/)